# Highly imbalanced data on C5.0 tree model

Tags: r, parameters, decision-tree, random-forest

I have a imbalanced dataset with only 87 target events "F" out of all 496,978 obs, since I would like to see a rule/tree, I chose to use the tree models, I have been following the codes in "Applied Predictive Modeling in R" book by Dr Max Kuhn, in chapter 16 this imbalance issue is well addressed.

Here is the sample data structure:

```
str(training[,predictors])
```

'data.frame':   496978 obs. of  36 variables:

$ Point_Of_Sale_Code   : Factor w/ 5 levels "c0","c2","c90",..: 3 3 5 5 3 3 5 5 5 5 ...

$ Delinquent_Amount               : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

$ Delinquent_Days_Count           : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

$ Overlimit_amt                   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

I tried the downsampling with random forest, it works well, with good auc= 0.9997 on test data, and confusion matrix

```
            Reference
Prediction      N      F
         N 140526      0
         F   1442     24
```

however, rf does not give me a specific rule, so I tried the code in the book exactly as:

```
library(rpart)

library(e1071)

  initialRpart <- rpart(flag ~ ., data = training,
                  control = rpart.control(cp = 0.0001))
  rpartGrid <- data.frame(.cp = initialRpart$cptable[, "CP"])

  cmat <- list(loss = matrix(c(0, 1, 20, 0), ncol = 2))
  set.seed(1401)

  cartWMod1 <- train(x = training[,predictors],
                     y = training$flag,
                     method = "rpart",
                     trControl = ctrlNoProb,
                     tuneGrid = rpartGrid,
                     metric = "Kappa",
                     parms = cmat)
  cartWMod1
```

I got the error msg below everytime, no matter what I tried, like convert all int data type to num type, not sure why I get this warning msg,

```
  Warning message:
  In ni[1:m] * nj[1:m] : ***NAs produced by integer overflow***

  Aggregating results
  Selecting tuning parameters
  Error in train.default(x = training[, predictors], y = training$flag,  : 
  ***final tuning parameters could not be determined***
```

I also tried the code for c5.0 package:

```
library(C50)

  c5Grid <- expand.grid(.model = c("tree", "rules"),
                  .trials = c(1, (1:10)*10),
                  .winnow = FALSE)

  finalCost <- matrix(c(0, 150, 1, 0), ncol = 2)
  rownames(finalCost) <- colnames(finalCost) <- levels(training$flag)

set.seed(1401)

      C5CostFit1 <- train(training[,predictors],
               training$flag,
               method = "C5.0",
               metric = "Kappa",
               tuneGrid = c5Grid,
               cost = finalCost,
               control = C5.0Control(earlyStopping = FALSE),
               trControl = ctrlNoProb)

C5CostCM1 <- confusionMatrix(predict(C5CostFit, training), training$flag)
```

I got this result, which classify all the target event F to be nonevent N, Is it possible that I can increase the cost penalty from 150 to larger to fix this issue? Thank you!

```
C5CostCM1

Confusion Matrix and Statistics

           Reference
  Prediction      N      F
           N 141968     ***24***
           F      0      0

           Accuracy : 0.9998          
             95% CI : (0.9997, 0.9999)
No Information Rate : 0.9998          
P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.554           
              Kappa : NA            
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 2.668e-06                                                 
        Sensitivity : 1.0000          
        Specificity : 0.0000          
     Pos Pred Value : 0.9998          
     Neg Pred Value :    NaN          
         Prevalence : 0.9998          
     Detection Rate : 0.9998          
   Detection Prevalence : 1.0000          
   Balanced Accuracy : 0.5000                                                    
    'Positive' Class : N
```

I have been googling this issue for the past week, but didn't see a solution, the code from the book work well though, but gives me error for my data... Any suggestion will be appriciated!! Thank you so much!

Comment: I am having the same problem...the imbalance problem is directly related to the fact of getting a lower Specificity. In order to solve this problem, we need to have a specific metric. Please take a look at the following references about how to face this problem using [C5.0](http://r-norberg.blogspot.com/2015/04/custom-caret-model.html) and [Random Forest](http://topepo.github.io/caret/custom_models.html#Illustration5). I have not solved yet my original problem, but I think the solution will be in this direction. Please let me know if you found any other way to face this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* that it's telling you that something in the output (i.e., the list) has NAs in it--the Kappa stat.

Using something like this:

```
results.matrix = confusionMatrix(data, reference)
results.df = as.data.frame(results.matrix[3])
summary(is.finite(results.df$overall))
```

Gives you this:

```
   Mode   FALSE    TRUE    NA's 
logical       1       6       0
```

So I'm guessing that's what it's picking up.